# Android WebView: Separate Cookie Jar

Tags: android, cookies, iframe, webview

### Background

Imagine having 2 Webviews in an Android Application:

- WebView#1 talks to `subdomain1.domain.com`. Let's assume the initial request loads via redirect to another URL that sets the cookies C1 at `*.domain.com`. All subdomains now have this cookie.
- WebView2 talks to `subdomain2.domain.com`. However, this wants to operate with a different cookie jar. More specifically, this needs cookie C2 (which will come from the Android App) and **C1 should not appear at all**.
- `C1` and `C2` need to be mutually exclusive.

But unfortunately:

1. All Android Webviews in a process share the [same singleton instance of the CookieJar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager).
2. **Therefore, any request going out of WebView2 will carry `C1` cookie (set at *.domain.com)**. Any attempt to clear cookies will directly impact all other webviews.
3. Let's say I have exceedingly tiny amount control over the server side of of `subdomain1.domain.com`. Like, it's going to be giant PITA to fiddle with modifying how cookies are sent from the server side.

### High Level Implementation detail

Each Webview has a static HTML that acts as a wrapper and has an `<iframe>` that loads up the actual URL of the content. So technically, the `subdomain*.domain.com` is loaded through an iframe. Or diagrammatically:

```
+=====================
|  Android App (can be modified)
|  +==============
|  | WebView1 (can be modified)
|  |   +=======
|  |   | <iframe> (can be modified)
|  |   |   +====
|  |   |   | <html> of subdomain2.domain.com (can be modified)
|  +-------------------------
|  +=============
|  | WebView2 
|  |   +=====
|  |   | <iframe> Same HTML as before
|  |   |  +====
|  |   |  |  <html> of subdomain1.domain.com (**can NOT be modified**)
|  |   |  |  Sets cookie at *.domain.com
```

The sandboxed `<iframe>` currently looks like:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-forms" ... >
```

### What I've tried:

I tried removing "allow-same-origin" -- with the understanding that it triggers the browser to treat the URL as a different domain. So effectively, `C1` will not be present. Now, to insert `C2`, I was planning on using postMessage(..) which will be handled by something that will set the cookie. But sadly, it also prevents cookies from being read or set. [Here's a demo to play around with](https://pastebin.com/BLijQ4B5). [Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2MDl.png). Turns out removing "allow-same-origin" is way too restrictive. Either no cookie jar at all, or shared cookie jar.

### What I am looking for

I am hoping to find a way to set the cookie `C2` for all requests from WebView2, and ensure `C1` cookie is not present (which would otherwise be present thanks to WebView1).

1. Is there a middle ground with allow-same-origin that sort of lets me treat the URL as being loaded from a different domain, but at the same time allow me to read/write cookies?
2. Is there any other way around the "X" of this "XY" problem?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, did you get any solution for this issue?

Comment: Hi, no I wasn't able to. It looks like with a Webview, there's really one shared process-wide cookiejar. I ended up moving the app from subdomain2 to subdomain1.

Comment: Thanks for replying :)